# D3 How to keep element same size while transform scale / translate

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, scale

This example illustrates my problem: https://bl.ocks.org/feketegy/ce9ab2efa9439f3c59c381f567522dd3

I have a couple of paths in a group element and I want to pan/zoom these elements except the blue rectangle path, which is in another group element.

The zooming and panning is done by applying `transform="translate(0,0) scale(1)` to the outer most group element then capturing the zoom delta and applying it to the `same-size` group element to keep it the same size.

This is working, but the blue rectangle position, which should remain the same size, is messed up, I would like to keep it in the same relative position to the other paths.

The rendered html structure looks like this:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <g class="outer-group" transform="translate(0,0)scale(1)">
    <path d="M100,100 L140,140 L200,250 L100,250 Z" fill="#cccccc" stroke="#8191A2" stroke-width="2px"></path>
    <path d="M400,100 L450,100 L450,250 L400,250 Z" fill="#cccccc" stroke="#8191A2" stroke-width="2px"></path>

    <g class="same-size-position" transform="translate(300,250)">
      <g class="same-size" transform="scale(1)">
        <path d="M0,0 L50,0 L50,50 L0,50 Z" fill="#0000ff"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've tried to get the X/Y position of the `same-size-position` group and create a delta from the translate x/y of the `outer-group`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: To me it looks like the blue rectangle keeps its correct position (that is, its top left corner does).

Comment: The calculation I'm looking for is how google maps does it with its POI (point-of-interest) icons, it remains the same size and in the same position relative to other paths. 


In my case there will be scenarios where the blue rectangle would be on top of other paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After dusting off my high school geometry books I found a solution.

You need to get the bounding box of the element you want to keep the same size of and calculate a matrix conversion on it like so:

```
const zoomDelta = 1 / d3.event.transform.k;

const sameSizeElem = d3.select('.same-size');
const bbox = sameSizeElem.node().getBBox();

const cx = bbox.x + (bbox.width / 2);
const cy = bbox.y + (bbox.height / 2);
const zx = cx - zoomDelta * cx;
const zy = cy - zoomDelta * cy;

sameSizeElem
  .attr('transform', 'matrix(' + zoomDelta + ', 0, 0, ' + zoomDelta + ', ' + zx + ', ' + zy + ')');
```

The matrix transformation will keep the relative position of the element which size remains the same and the other elements will pan/zoom.